# A small but moderately powerful graphics card?

Tags: graphics-cards

I have a "Slim line case" with a flex ATX form factor motherboard, and I want a moderate graphics card. Something close to a GTS 450. A Radeon HD 5450 works but i would prefer more power. But It needs to fit in my case, so a more compact size. Length doesn't really matter but it can't take up 2 spaces in the back of the PC. I'm just using it for light gaming. It must have a VGA port and a DVI/VGA/displayport because I am using dual monitors. (Both with VGA but I have adapters for DVI and displayport.) It should be able to run all aspects of Windows 10.

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: Under $50 would be great, but I may go more.

Answer (score 1):

It's a toss up between a [Radeon RX-460 and a Geforce GTX-750](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/Radeon-RX-460-vs-GeForce-GTX-750) for me:

[image: RX-460 vs GTX-750]

Here are a few specific UPCs:

Radeon RX-460: 778656073524

Geforce GTX-750: 843368027933

The RX-460 has DVI and DisplayPort, and there are [single-slot](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MU015Q1) models available.

The GTX-750 has both DVI and DisplayPort, and there are [single-slot](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SOXMPJY) models available.

**References**

- [Build Your Own Single-Slot GeForce GTX 750 Ti - Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/single-slot-geforce-gtx-750-ti,3761.html)
- [Comparison table: GTX-750 vs RX-460](https://us.hardware.info/comparisontable/3337585/geen_username/graphics-cards-comparison-table-gtx-750-vs-rx-460)